# Excel VBA 1004 Error with named range formula

Tags: vba, excel

I am tinkering with a program but I get an error that I cant place.

> Error is 1004

Code:

```
Source_1_Criteria = "Factuur"
Source_1_Name = Range("MDM_MDM_Tool_List").Find(what:=Source_1_Criteria).Offset(0, 2).Value
Source_1_Area = Range("MDM_MDM_Tool_List").Find(what:=Source_1_Criteria).Offset(0, 4).Value

ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=Source_1_Name, RefersTo:=Source_1_Area
```

The last line gives me the error.
I know its something in the 3 line.
The result in the 3 line results in error with current contents in the cell

```
=VERSCHUIVING(archief!$A$2;0;0;1;AANTALARG(archief!$A$2:archief!$Y$2))
```

When I change the contents to `=archief!$A$2` the code works.
But when I manually copy/paste the formula in a named range it works....

So to my calculation:
Formula = Works
Code = Works

those 2 together gives

> error 1004

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA create a Named range from formula in worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48093227/excel-vba-create-a-named-range-from-formula-in-worksheet)

Comment: You should update your original question rather than creating a duplicate question.

Comment: How are `Source_1_Name` and `Source_1_Area` declared? (or are they?)

Comment: Source_1_Name = Range("MDM_MDM_Tool_List").Find(what:=Source_1_Criteria).Offset(0, 2).Value
Source_1_Area = Range("MDM_MDM_Tool_List").Find(what:=Source_1_Criteria).Offset(0, 4).Value

Comment: No, I mean which data type?  (for example, is there a `Dim Source_1_Area as _____` statement?)

Comment: no thare is not ;( becouse i like the formula that is the resut of Source_1_Area to be placed as a formula and not as a value.

Comment: also if you add these lines right before the line that gives the error: `Debug.Print "Source_1_Name: " & Source_1_Name` and `Debug.Print "Source_1_Area: " & Source_1_Area`, what does it return in the Immediate Window?  (If you can't see the Immediate window in the Visual Basic Editor, press `CTRL+G`.)

Comment: Thank you for the code, it gives me the result that i would like to see
    Source_1_Name: Archief_Factuur_Headers
    Source_1_Area: =VERSCHUIVING(archief!$A$2;0;0;1;AANTALARG(archief!$A$2:archief!$Y$2))

Comment: braX The Name Archief is the name of the Worksheet is use :)

Comment: Then the English version of `VERSCHUIVING`

Comment: BraX, verschuiving is the name of the formula in Excel it self (from Holland)
its just a value that VBA has to copy paste. Could that give problems??
Becouse i used in my last projects a lot of the formula code of Holland

Comment: VERSCHUIVING is OFFSET and AANTALARG is COUNTA

Comment: try `RefersToLocal:=` instead of `RefersTo:=`

Comment: thank you for the Tip, but i got the same error

Comment: i see now, the Error 1004 says the formula is incorrect, but wen i place it in a named range manualy it does work...

Comment: @brax.  Took me a while as VERSCHUIVING translates as SHIFT on Google (which makes sense once you've figured out it's OFFSET).

Comment: this is the formule that Excel Gives when i use the formule while recording a macro. "=OFFSET(archief!R2C1,0,0,1,COUNTA(archief!R2C1:archief!R2C25))"

When i use this formula directly in VBA code then the code works. but when i place this formule in my Excel Cell, then i get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula you should have in place of `=VERSCHUIVING(archief!$A$2;0;0;1;AANTALARG(archief!$A$2:archief!$Y$2))` should be this one:-

=ADRES(2;1;;;"Archief") & ":" & ADRES(2;AANTALARG(Archief!$A$2:$Y$2))

Below is code which I tested thoroughly. It works with the formula I supplied yesterday (above). You can use Edit/Replace to restore your original variable names in the code below.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Dutch()
    ' 05 Jan 2018

    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim SrcCrit As String
    Dim SrcName As Variant
    Dim SrcArea As String
    Dim Sp() As String
    Dim Rng As Range

    Set Wb = ActiveWorkbook                 ' could be ThisWorkbook
    Set Ws = ActiveSheet                    ' could be another sheet
    SrcCrit = "Factuur"
    Set Rng = Ws.Range("ToolList").Find(What:=SrcCrit)
    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
        SrcName = Rng.Offset(0, 2).Value
'        Debug.Print SrcName
        SrcArea = Rng.Offset(0, 4).Value
'        Debug.Print SrcArea
        Sp = Split(SrcArea, "!")
        If UBound(Sp) Then
            If Left(Sp(0), 1) = "'" Then Sp(0) = Mid(Sp(0), 2)
            If Right(Sp(0), 1) = "'" Then Sp(0) = Left(Sp(0), Len(Sp(0)) - 1)
        Else
            Sp = Split(Ws.Name & "|" & Sp(0), "|")
        End If

        Set Rng = Wb.Worksheets(Sp(0)).Range(Sp(1))
'        Debug.Print Rng.Worksheet.Name, Rng.Address
        On Error Resume Next
        Wb.Names(SrcName).Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
        Wb.Names.Add Name:=SrcName, RefersTo:=Rng
'        With Wb.Names(SrcName)
'            Debug.Print .Name, .RefersTo
'        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

I found that error 1004 is a little complicated in the above context because such an error will occur when a faulty Name exists in the workbook, such as may have been created by your original code. In that case the error indicates the existence of an unrecognised element in the workbook which may be totally unrelated to the code you are intending to test run. 1004 errors of this nature are commonly caused by compatibility issues, not even related to names. Google for `_xlfn IERROR`

I got a persistent 1004 error while developing the above code because I had named the offsets from the found range as "first" to "fourth" which allocated "second" to the new named range. `Wb.Names("Second").Name` correctly returned "second" but `Wb.Names(ScrName).Name` trigered error 1004 - just your complaint. The error went away when I found out that `SECOND()` is a worksheet function and changed the name in the offset cell.

Comment: That'll return the address as a text string while the original will return a reference to the address.  `$A$2:INDEX(archief!$A$2:$Y$2,,COUNTA(archief!$A$2:$Y$2))` would replicate the original formula in a non-volatile way.

Comment: I have added working code to my answer. By comparing, you should now be able to find out which part of your code caused it to fail.